# WSO2 APIM: Send email to users added via the management console

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

We have the WSO2 API Manager deployed and working, although we are unable to figure out an issue about users addition. We want to add the users via the management console (Carbon) and after being added we want the user to receive an email saying that his/her account was successfully created.

Although there is documentation for a workflow extension when the user signs up, we were unable to find any documentation regarding the matter we've pointed out, is this possible to achieve via the API Manager or with some kind workflow extension?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: We are using WSO2 API Manager 1.10.0.

Comment: For which version of API Manager you want to have this feature?

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to mention, we are using the API Manager 1.10.0. I'm editing the question to add this information.

Comment: Do you want to send only a notification to the user? or do you want to send user password through the mail?

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is to create a user through the management console and allow the created user to define a password, you can configure APIM server to support 'Ask password from user' feature. (In this feature, APIM server administration can create a user through the management console and provide the email address of the user, so that user can set the password through the redirection URL provided in the email). To configure 'Ask password from user' feature follow the instructions given in https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Creating+Users+Using+the+Ask+Password+Option.

If you want the APIM server administrator to set the username and password through the APIM management console and only send a notification to the user that his/her account is created successfully, then you have to write a custom component, because this is not supported by default.